# psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "XXX" even after setting password

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I can say with some certainty that I have a user and with the password of `test`. But no-matter what I try I cannot connect through this user.

```
postgres=# \du
                                    List of roles
 Role name  |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 depotadmin | Superuser                                                  | {}
 postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

postgres=# alter user depotadmin password 'test';
ALTER ROLE
```

I am setting the users password:

```
hutber@laptop:~/site/depot_fe$ sudo -u postgres psql depotdb 
[sudo] password for hutber:        
psql (10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

depotdb=# alter user depotadmin password 'test';
ALTER ROLE
```

However now I can't login:

```
hutber@laptop:~/programs/pgAdmin4/pgAdmin4$ psql depotdb -U depotadmin -W
Password for user depotadmin: 
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "depotadmin"
```

Comment: You must inspect your [hba](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file. Also, try to connect with -h 127.0.0.1 to change connection type from local domain to tcp (just a test to see if pg_hba has different rules for each connection method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must inspect your [hba](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file. To check where it is, use the following command on psql:

```
SHOW hba_file;
```

Probably your hba file has an entry with local connection type configured to peer auth type. You could change from peer to md5. Something like that:

```
#old entry (connection type, database, user, auth type)
#This line means: every connection made by unix-domain sockets (local), 
#for any database and with any user will use peer auth type
local      *  *  peer   

#new entry
local      depotdb  depotadmin  md5
```

After that, you must restart your cluster or signal the backend to reload its configurations:

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```